# How do I create subdomain redirects using .htaccess?

Tags: apache

I have a main domain MYDOMAIN.COM

I want to make it easy for me to remember my Google Apps email URL, so I just want to redirect gmail.MYDOMAIN.CCOM to my Google Apps email URL using .htaccess to do a redirect.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly indirect answer...

Why don't you just setup DNS for **gmail.mydomain.com** and instruct Google Apps (via admin panel) to respond to that subdomain?  The instructions are right in the admin panel, and very simple to follow.

It's a snap.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@Matthew Iselin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051886/how-do-i-create-subdomain-redirects-using-htaccess/1051898#1051898), this should work in a .htaccess in the directory that represents the root of your subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://wherever.gmail.com/
```

or whatever the url is.

Without [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you can use [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Redirect permanent / http://wherever.gmail.com/
```

Although, the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) solution is "better", it's not enabled on all server. [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) however should be.

Comment: Does a DNS entry for the machinename "gmail" or "whatever" need to be established for this to work? I mean, you can't just surf to wwwxyzanything.example.com and have it resolve to your "www" hosting, now, can you?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be a rhetoric question... The correct comment I should have left should have indicated that you'll also need to have control of (and know how to configure) your domain's DNS record... The example monoxide left suggests that such a setup would exist in a separate root directory on your server. Other approaches might dump you into the same directory...

Comment: Most servers are setup to have seperate directories for each subdomain. In the case you are using a server that isn't, I don't think you'd be asking this question. There is an option to setup a DNS CNAME for gmail.MYDOMAIN.COM -> wherever.gmail.com too, but the question was specifically about doing this in .htaccess

Comment: Is there a way I can create it in such a way as not needing to set up a directory in the subdomain?  I'm not sure if that works....so I'd like the RewriteRule itself, if possible, to read the subdomain...for expediency I changed the DNS cname.

Comment: Like I said in my comment, if you have access to your domain name's DNS then you can simply add a CNAME to google apps... but not everyone does, and you asked for an answer inside apache, which is a perfectly valid question too :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apache, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) will allow you to create redirects like this.